# How to GROUP BY date,id By checking overall sum of transactions in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to group by table using client_code,date and filial. But I also need to check overall turnover summ between given dates. **client_code = substr(CODE_ACCOUNT, 10, 8)**

Table **ACCOUNT_TABLE**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CODE_FILIAL    |  OPER_DAY           | CODE_ACCOUNT        | CREDIT          |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
00825          | 2020-01-02 12:32:22 |20210000700123343001 | 124544112    |
00825          | 2020-02-23 21:45:00 |20210000700123343001 | 523553452.23   |
00825          | 2020-02-23 21:45:00 |20212000700224543001 | 245565345.23  |
00825          | 2020-02-10 09:18:00 |20212000700224543001 | 987565345.23  |
00825          | 2020-03-21 14:45:00 |20212000700253374001 | 100053523.23   |
00825          | 2020-04-03 18:45:00 |20212000700123343001 | 133354523.23   |
00825          | 2020-05-18 23:00:00 |20210000700123343001 | 892334523.23   |
```

Below what I have tried so far

```
SELECT substr(CODE_ACCOUNT, 10, 8) AS CLIENT_CODE,CODE_ACCOUNT,oborot,mnth,CODE_FILIAL FROM (
                        SELECT CODE_ACCOUNT,sum(CREDIT)/100 as oborot,to_char(s.OPER_DAY, 'YYYY-MM') AS mnth,CODE_FILIAL
                                 FROM ACCOUNT_TABLE s
                       WHERE s.OPER_DAY >= to_date('01.01.2020', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
                         AND s.OPER_DAY < to_date('01.07.2020', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
                         AND s.CODE_FILIAL in ('00820','00825')
                         AND substr(s.CODE_ACCOUNT, 1, 8) IN ('20208000','20210000','20212000')
            GROUP BY CODE_ACCOUNT,to_char(s.OPER_DAY, 'YYYY-MM'),s.CODE_FILIAL
                ) rs ORDER BY rs.oborot DESC
```

**Result i took:**

```
CLIENT_CODE    | CODE_ACCOUNT         | OBOROT        | MNTH       | CODE_FILIAL|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
00123343       | 20210000900123343001 | 124544112     | 2020-01    | 00825      |
00123343       | 20210000900123343001 | 523553452.23  | 2020-02    | 00825      |
00123343       | 20212000700123343001 | 133354523.23  | 2020-04    | 00825      |
00123343       | 20210000900123343001 | 892334523.23  | 2020-05    | 00825      |
00224543       | 20212000700224543001 | 1233130690.46 | 2020-02    | 00825      |
00253374       | 20212000700253374001 | 100053523.23  | 2020-03    | 00825      |
```

In this case I am trying to take 6 month. As you see that last data is not needed to me. Cause it is less than **1000000000** . I want for one client_code during 6 month overall summ is greater that **1000000000** number.

**Result I want**

```
CLIENT_CODE    | CODE_ACCOUNT         | OBOROT        | MNTH       | CODE_FILIAL|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
00123343       | 20210000900123343001 | 124544112     | 2020-01    | 00825      |
00123343       | 20210000900123343001 | 523553452.23  | 2020-02    | 00825      |
00123343       | 20212000700123343001 | 133354523.23  | 2020-04    | 00825      |
00123343       | 20210000900123343001 | 892334523.23  | 2020-05    | 00825      |
00224543       | 20212000700224543001 | 1233130690.46 | 2020-02    | 00825      |
```

In above result **client_code = 00253374** is not taken because oborot summa is less than **1000000000**. To sum up I need to add WHERE clause somewhere to check all summ. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the having clause in yoir inner query as follows:

```
GROUP BY CODE_ACCOUNT,to_char(s.OPER_DAY, 'YYYY-MM'),s.CODE_FILIAL
Having sum(CREDIT)/100 >= 1000000000
```

**Update**:

You need to use the analytical function as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select t.*, sum(OBOROT) over (partition by client_code, CODE_FILIAL) as sm
From (<your_existing_query>) t)
Where sm >= 1000000000;
```

Comment: It is not working because it skips summ which is less than 1000000000 for particular client_code. But overall summ for the period of 6 months can be more than 1000000000. Assume one client had 100000000 for 2020-01 and 950000000 for 2020-03 and overall more thant 1000000000. The way you offered just skips for the month of 2020-01

Comment: Your updated answer is working fine If i remove CODE_FILIAL inside over scope. Is there some faster way to do this task? Now I have more than 10mln data and it groups by whole table and then compares sum.